# torch7 : how to connect the neurons of the same layer?

Tags: neural-network, torch

Is it possible to implement, using torch, an architecture that connects the neurons of the same layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is called a recurrent neural network. Note that it needs quite different type of structure, input data, and training algorithms to work well.

There is the [**rnn**](https://github.com/Element-Research/rnn) library for Torch to work with recurrent neural networks.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the rnn library can connect the output of each node to it's own input. It provides no way of connecting different neurons in the same layer

Comment: Update: I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/Element-Research/rnn/blob/master/LSTM.lua) of the LSTM implementation and it is fully connected inside the layer. I tried to retract my downvote but can't

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Torch has everything that other languages have: logical operations, reading/writing operations, array operations. That's all what needed for implementing any kind of neural network. If to take into account that torch has usage of CUDA you can even implement neural network which can work faster then some C# or java implementations. Performance improvement can depend from number of if/else during one iteration